# How do I get all Y axis labels to show on plotly Gannt chart?

Tags: plotly, label, yaxis

Other answers I found said to set y axis ticks: 1, but I cannot figure out where to add this into my code to make it work.

My current code:

```
fig = px.timeline(df, x_start="Offer Date", x_end="Decision Date", y="Employer")
fig.update_yaxes(autorange="reversed")  # otherwise tasks are listed from the bottom up
fig.show()
```

While all of the bars appear on the chart, only every other yaxis label shows up.

Comment: I think this may be the solution; fig.update_layout(yaxis=dict(dtick=1))

Comment: Did you get the asnwer of not?

Comment: I did. Do I need to update it somewhere to show it as solved?

Comment: Yes, you should post the answer for people to learn how to solve your problem if they have it one day! :)

Answer (score 0):

As @PythonBear pointed out, adding
`fig.update_layout(yaxis={'dtick':1})`
solves this issue, it did the trick to me.